# Continuity of Graph when the function because of the form 0/0

Tags: limits

Will a graph be continuous where there exists a limit found through L'hopital's rule. For example:

$f(x)=\frac{x^2-9}{x-3}$ at $x=3$

Comment: the graph looks continuous but it is not.

Comment: Formally, the function is not defined at $x=3$. You need to "fill in" the undefined parts with limits to extend the range of the function. In this case, simply write $(x-3)(x+3)/(x-3)\to x+3$ which is not a strict equality but a limiting process.

Answer (score 0):

There is no notion of "continuity" of a graph. A graph is a visual representation of a function and can itself not be continuous. The function, on the other hand, can be continuous.

Since your function equals $$f(x)=\frac{(x-3)(x+3)}{x-3},$$ it is clear that, for $x\neq 3$, the function is actually $f(x) = x+3$. For $x=3$, the function is not defined.

What you can say is that the function has a limit when $x$ approaches $3$ and that that limit equals $6$. This means that there exists a continuous function $g$ which equals $f$ wherever $f$ is defined. Of course, the function $g$ is simply $$g(x)=x+3.$$

Comment: Here is the exact question from: sat.collegeboard.org          If   f(x) = x+3 and g(x) = x^2-9/(x-3) which of the following 
statements are true about the graphs of f and g in the 
xy-plane?
 I. The graphs are exactly the same.
 II. The graphs are the same except when x=3 .
 III. The graphs have an infinite number of points in common.
(A) I only (B) II only (C) III only
(D) I and III (E) II and III                                       The answer is E. Is the question correctly framed?

Comment: Yesm the answer is correctly framed. The question says nothing about continuity of graphs. Also, (E) is the correct answer because the graph of $g$ contains all the points that the graph of $f$ does, except for $x=3$.